# Bash shell string contains print full word

Tags: string, bash, shell, for-loop, contains

the code:

```
READLINE=$(sudo /bin/cat < "file.txt");
IFS=$';'
for i in $READLINE;
do
txt=$txt" ""$i";
done
unset IFS

for x in $arr
do
if [[ $txt == *$x* ]] ; then
echo "$x is in the txt file";
```

output file.txt

> telecomtest;yess;

output for loop:

> telecomtest is in the txt file
>   tel is in the txt file

I want only print the full word not a part of it. 
that means only print telecomtest and not tel.

How can i make this work?

Comment: `[[ " $txt " == *" $x "* ]]`

Comment: your first part is extremely redundant. `cat file.text | tr ';\n' '  '` does the work.

Comment: What is `$arr`? It appears it contains telecomtest and tel. Just remove tel from $arr and you're done. And please learn some shell grammar; most semicolons in your snippet are completely useless (i.e. can be removed without changing the program).

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr Sure about that? Note the sudo. And you shouldn't talk about **extreme redundancy** and promote a **useless use of cat** :-)

Comment: You can use regular quotes for `IFS=';'`. `$'...'` is only needed to process some C-style escape codes.

Comment: Please read [Bash FAQ 001](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001)

Comment: @Jens - wouldn't input redirection happen before `sudo` elevates privilege? Try `sudo cat < /etc/shadow` and you'll see you will still get permission denied error but `sudo cat /etc/shadow` will work flawlessly. But I'm digressing. @thatotherguy's suggestion fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `$arr` appears to contain both `telecomtest` and `tel`. Since you don't show us how `$arr` is assigned, everything else is speculation. Did you delete too much of the script to post it here? There's also a `fi` missing to make this valid shell grammar.

Please provide a minimal runnable script for us, including some stripped down contents of `file.txt` so we are able to reproduce the problem. Often this will uncover the problem right away.